# Pandas merger multiple rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hi I have a data frame which goes like this:

```
index event  action   date
0     event1 action1  date1
1     event2 action2  date1
2     event3 action3  date2
3     event4 action4  date2
```

I want to merge both columns and row. I have already merged the rows using `groupby` and `lambda function` by cannot merge both the rows and columns to get a output to something similar

```
index  final_actions               date
0      for event1 do action1 and   date1
       for event2 do action2 
1      for event3 do action3 and   date2
       for event4 do action4
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this, `groupby` + `zip`

```
(
    df.groupby('date')['event', 'action']
        .apply(lambda x:
               " and ".join([f"for {x} do {y}"
                             for x, y in zip(x['event'], x['action'])]))
)
```